# Compatible Spring Eureka Version

Tags: spring-boot, maven, spring-cloud, netflix-eureka, spring-cloud-netflix

I am using below on pom.xml but i am not able to start the application  due to error
I don't want to downgrade the spring boot starter parent version.Is there any solution?

```
<parent>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
        <version>2.5.4</version>
    </parent>


<dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.cloud</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-cloud-starter-netflix-eureka-client</artifactId>
            <version>2.2.9.RELEASE</version>
        </dependency>
```

I am getting the belwo error

> org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error
> creating bean with name 'configurationPropertiesBeans' defined in
> class path resource
> [org/springframework/cloud/autoconfigure/ConfigurationPropertiesRebinderAutoConfiguration.class]:
> Post-processing of merged bean definition failed; nested exception is
> java.lang.IllegalStateException:  Failed to introspect Class
> [org.springframework.cloud.context.properties.ConfigurationPropertiesBeans]
> from ClassLoader [sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader@659e0bfd]

Comment: Never add version to the spring cloud subprojects.

Comment: @Tristate ok but why?

Comment: Otherwise you run the risk of choosing incompatible versions. The modules automatically get the correct versions from parent.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You should add Spring Cloud 2020.0.3 that is compatible with Spring Boot 2.5.x by including the BOM in your `dependencyManagement` section:

```
<dependencyManagement>
    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.cloud</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-cloud-dependencies</artifactId>
            <version>2020.0.3</version>
            <type>pom</type>
            <scope>import</scope>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>
</dependencyManagement>
```

You can find an overview of Spring Cloud / Spring Boot compatibility on [the Spring Cloud website](https://spring.io/projects/spring-cloud) (see the table *Release train Spring Boot compatibility*).

Once this is added, you don't need to target a specific version of Spring Cloud Eureka. Instead, you can include the Eureka dependency as follows:

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.springframework.cloud</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-cloud-starter-netflix-eureka-client</artifactId>
</dependency>
```

Comment: .Yes i generated the same pom.xml from spring initilaiser .But as soon as i add `dependecyManagement` tag. i get tehe belwo parsing error of pom.xml
`Project build error: Non-parseable POM C:\Users\.m2\repository\io\zipkin\brave\brave-bom\5.13.2\brave-bom-5.13.2.pom: 
start tag not allowed in epilog but got p (position: END_TAG seen ...verning permissions and limitations under\n  
  the License.\n\n-->\n<p... @341:3) `

Comment: Its working  now.I deleted the workspace and imported the project again.Thanks